# Why am I getting "no sources available" when adding/editing a field of type Assets?

Tags: fieldtypes

Anyone else suffering from this issue after doing an upgrade/update?

This may be in the category of bugs because it appeared to be working earlier today before upgrading Craft from the Free version to the Pro version I've been unable to save fields that are of type "Assets".

Current install is:
Craft Pro 2.1.2564 Released on 7/15/2014

The issue is pretty straight forward. Attempting to save or edit a field that is set to the type "assets" fails.

Additionally, the sources available for assets on the create new field page incorrectly indicate that no sources are available. Error reads "No sources exist yet."

[image: see "no sources available" warning even though there are sources.]

I did a run down where I verified the directory paths were properly set, and the permissions for those directories were also properly set. Both checked out okay.

Additionally, uploads to all my defined sources work as expected. This issue seems to only impact fields.

Result of trying to save or edit a field produces an error that appears saying "save failed". No further warnings show up.

Here's a shot of the available sources defined on my install, these were defined after my upgrade if that makes a difference.

[image]

Comment: And all that changed was you updated from "Personal" to "Pro" edition?

Comment: Yes, just did the upgrade and things started failing. I was also able to create fields of other types just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I would not consider this to be the best solution, but I was able to fix my issue.

I downloaded a fresh copy of Craft and replaced the craft/app/ directory with the fresh download. This restored all functionality back to normal. Not the most ideal, but it worked.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Sounds like something was just plain corrupted (or missing) in the `app` folder. Replacing the entire folder is actually a legitimate solution, there are really no downsides. It's basically the same as if you had performed a manual update.

Answer (score 1):

Does *Update Asset Indexes* from the control panel help? (you might as well *Clear Caches* and *Rebuild Search Indexes* while you're at it)

Answer (score 0):

If [Marion's way](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1229/177) doesn't work, it could also be possible that while updating something got messed up in the `/craft/storage/runtime/` directory. Try deleting it, and check again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that didn't work though.